# Написал код. Но ничего не получается, выходит ошибка: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
        <script>
            

            // Данные, массив объектов Recipes
            const data = [
                {
                    name:"Baked Salmon",
                    ingredients: [
                        { name: "Salmon", amount: 1, measurement: "1 lb" },
                        { name: "Pine Nuts", amount: 1, measurement: "cup" },
                        { name: "Butter Lettuce", amount: 2, measurement: "cups" },
                        { name: "Yellow Squash", amount: 1, measurement: "med" },
                        { name: "Olive Oil", amount: 0.5, measurement: "cup" },
                        { name: "Garlic", amount: 3, measurement: "cloves" }
                    ],

                    steps: [
                        "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees.",
                        "Sqread the olive oil around a glass baking dish.",
                        "Add the salmon, garlic, and pine nuts to the dish.",
                        "Bake for 15 minutes",
                        "Remove from oven. Add the lettuce and serve",
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Frish Tacos",
                    ingredients: [
                        { name: "Whitefish", amount: 1, measurement: "1 lb" },
                        { name: "Cheese", amount: 1, measurement: "cup" },
                        { name: "Iceberg Lettuce", amount: 2, measurement: "cups" },
                        { name: "Tomatoes", amount: 2, measurement: "large" },
                        { name: "Tortillas", amount: 3, measurement: "med" }
                    ],
                    steps: [
                        "Cook the fish on the grill untill cooked through",
                        "Place the fish on the 3 tortillas",
                        "Top them with lettuce"
                    ]
                }
            ];

            //  Функциональный компонент, предназначенный для Recipes

            function Recipe({ name, ingredients, steps}) {
                return (
                    <section id={name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-")}>
                        <h1> {name}</h1>
                        <ul className="ingredients">
                            {ingredients.map((ingredint, i) =>(
                                <li key={i}>{ingredient.name}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                        <section className="instructions">
                            <h2>Cooking Instructions</h2>
                            {steps.map((step, i) => (
                                <p key="i">{step}</p>
                            ))}
                        </section>
                    </section>
                );
            }

            // Функциональный компонент предназначенный для Menu

            function Menu( {title, recipes}) {
                return (
                    <article>
                         <header>
                            <h1>{title}</h1>
                        </header>
                        <div className="recipes">
                            {recipes.map((recipe, i) => (
                                <Recipe key={1} {...recipe} />
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </article>
                );
            }


            ReactDOM.render(
                <Menu recipes={data} title="Delicious Recipes" />,
                document.getElementById("root")
            );
        </script>
```

Comment: Где выходит? От кого выходит? Когда выходит? Что вообще происходит?

Comment: Ну а вообще пихать jsx-код внутрь тега `<script>` это заведомо провальная идея, потому что веб-браузеры вообще-то не поддерживают jsx

Comment: ошибка выходит в браузере

Comment: Браузеры не поддерживают jsx

Comment: а как все же решить проблему

Comment: Или отказаться от использования jsx, или использовать jsx там, где он поддерживается, например в сборщиках фронтенда

Comment: Выглядит, как будто это копипаста, либо вы взяли проект, который не понимаете. Вам нужно разобраться как работает react. Например [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) написано как подружить jsx с браузером, либо собрать проект